# How to get more paths than the shortest path between nodes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, nodes, shortest-path

in d3.js I am using a fuction called `path` to get the shortest path between 2 nodes.
The API says this:

> ## node.path(target) <>
>
> Returns the shortest path through the hierarchy from this node to the
>   specified target node. The path starts at this node, ascends to the
>   least common ancestor of this node and the target node, and then
>   descends to the target node.

With this definition i created a new array to save the data between 2 nodes. I am able to click on a first node called `beginNode` and on a second node, which is `d`. It works very good and the shortest path between them is saved in the array `shortest_path`:

```
 .on("click", function(d, i) //Hier beginnt große "click"-Funktion
              {
shortest_path = beginNode && beginNode.path(d) || [];.....
```

Sometimes there are many ways to get the path between 2 nodes, not only the shortest paths, also longer paths. Now, my goal is to store more paths between the 2 clicked nodes into that array or another array. But unfortunally, d3,js only offer that shortest path function. I hope some of you can help. Would be Djikstra  a right solution for this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [k shortest paths problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing).  You can solve it using a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm called [Eppstein's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing#Algorithm)